# Is is possible to concurrently export data?

Tags: python, parallel-processing

I have a Python program which executes below steps:

1. Look for .sql file present in particular folder
2. Create a List with all `.sql` file name
3. Create a database connection
4. Execute `for` loop for each file name present in list created in step 2.

   1. Read .sql file
   2. Execute query mentioned in .sql file against database
   3. Export data in to file
   4. Repeat step 4 for all 15 files

This works fine and as expected. However, each file is exported in serial fashion (one after another). Is there any way, I can start exporting all 15 files at a same time?

Comment: Threading: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/threading.html.

Comment: Yes, there are ways to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can actually call all 15 files parallel. Here is an example. I am calling request 4 times with different parameters on a functions.

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import random,time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

URL = 'http://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts'

def quote_stream():
    '''
    Quoter streamer
    '''
    param = dict(page=random.randint(1, 1000))
    quo = requests.get(URL, params=param)

    if quo.ok:
        data = quo.json()
        author = data[0]['title'].strip()

        content = bs(data[0]['content'], 'html5lib').text.strip()

        print(f'{content}\n-{author}\n')

    else:
        print('Connection Issues :(')

def multi_qouter(workers=4):
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=workers) as executor:
        _ = [executor.submit(quote_stream) for i in range(workers)]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    now = time.time()

    multi_qouter(workers=4)

    print(f'Time taken {time.time()-now:.2f} seconds')
```

The point is create a function that runs one file from start to finish(quote_stream). Then call that function with different files in different threads(multi_qouter). For a function that takes parameters as yours, you just place them [executor.submit(quote_stream,file) for file in files] and set max_workers=len(files), where files is a list of your sql files to be passed in that function.

Comment: got it. one question. _ = [executor.submit(quote_stream) for i in range(workers)] in this line what is meaning of underscore which is placed in first.

Comment: Nothing, you don’t need it